# php eval function in iframe

Tags: php, iframe, eval

i got an iframe in an echo:

```
<iframe width='100%' height='100'>$content</iframe>
$content = eval ( "\$bugs = \"" . gettemplate ('bugs') . "\";" );
```

but it doesnt work.

how can i use the eval function from php to show the page in an iframe?

thnx!

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to use eval here? (And you appear to be trying to use $content before you assign any data to it, which isn't going to do anything useful)

Comment: And to "show a page in an iframe" you use the `src` attribute. The child nodes of the iframe element are the alternative content for when frames are not supported or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

> Refer the following code

```
<?php
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';
echo $str. "\n";
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str. "\n";
?>
```

Comment: i dont understand how to do this with an html page

Comment: It is not do anything difference. The first echo will not interpolate $string value. But the second echo will interpolate the $string value, because of the eval.